# Onesided limit of integral

Tags: integration, limits

Let a function $f$ from 0 to $\infty$  be continuous and define $F$ by 
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t)dt $$

How can I show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}F(x) = f(0)$

Comment: Near $0$, $f(x)\approx f(0)$, by the continuity of $f$. Then $F(x)\approx {f(0)\cdot x\over x}=f(0)$. This can be made precise with some epsilonics, and is just using the usual proof of one of the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = f(0)$. Hence, by L'Hospital's rule,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} F(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^x f(t)\, dt}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\, dt}{\frac{d}{dx}(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = f(0)$$

Comment: Arh okay, I thought about L'hospital's rule but didn't know what to do with the norminator, but written like this it's actually quite simple thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $\int f(t)dt=G(t).$
Then:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}F(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{G(x)-G(0)}{x}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{G(0+h)-G(0)}{h}=G'(0)=f(0)$$

Comment: What does "$0+$" stand for?

Comment: @danzimm I fixed,  was mant to be one sided limit